# libx264のインストールについて質問です。

Tags: raspberry-pi, ffmpeg, raspbian

ffmpegのエンコードでnot found libx264とでたので調べたところ、/usr/lib/になかったのでインストールしようとしたんですが何回やってもできなくてここに質問しました。
私がやったのはx264をgit cloneでダウンロードしてコンパイルしました。

- git cloneでx264のダウンロード
- x264のディレクトリ内でconfigureの実行
- その後、makeとmake installを実行

しかし、以上を実行しても/usr/lib/にはなくて/usr/local/bin/にx264が追加されただけでした。
これはインストールするものを間違っているのでしょうか？
また、もしlibx264をインストールできたとしてもすぐにffmpegで使えますか？
いれたあとにffmpegをまたコンパイルする必要があるんでしょうか

よろしくお願いします。

追記

使っているOSはraspbianです。
configureの実行結果は

```
platform:      ARM
byte order:    little-endian
system:        LINUX
cli:           yes
libx264:       internal
shared:        no
static:        no
asm:           yes
interlaced:    yes
avs:           avxsynth
lavf:          yes
ffms:          no
mp4:           no
gpl:           yes
thread:        posix
opencl:        yes
filters:       resize crop select_every 
debug:         no
gprof:         no
strip:         no
PIC:           no
bit depth:     8
chroma format: all
```

このようにでました。
makeの結果は以下の通りです。

```
rm -f libx264.a
ar rc libx264.a  common/mc.o common/predict.o common/pixel.o common/macroblock.o common/frame.o common/dct.o common/cpu.o common/cabac.o common/common.o common/osdep.o common/rectangle.o common/set.o common/quant.o common/deblock.o common/vlc.o common/mvpred.o common/bitstream.o encoder/analyse.o encoder/me.o encoder/ratecontrol.o encoder/set.o encoder/macroblock.o encoder/cabac.o encoder/cavlc.o encoder/encoder.o encoder/lookahead.o common/threadpool.o common/arm/mc-c.o common/arm/predict-c.o common/opencl.o encoder/slicetype-cl.o common/arm/cpu-a.o common/arm/pixel-a.o common/arm/mc-a.o common/arm/dct-a.o common/arm/quant-a.o common/arm/deblock-a.o common/arm/predict-a.o
ranlib libx264.a
gcc -o x264  x264.o input/input.o input/timecode.o input/raw.o input/y4m.o output/raw.o output/matroska.o output/matroska_ebml.o output/flv.o output/flv_bytestream.o filters/filters.o filters/video/video.o filters/video/source.o filters/video/internal.o filters/video/resize.o filters/video/cache.o filters/video/fix_vfr_pts.o filters/video/select_every.o filters/video/crop.o filters/video/depth.o input/avs.o input/thread.o input/lavf.o libx264.a -ldl -L.  -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lxcb -lX11 -lasound -lSDL -lz -lswresample -lswscale -lavutil -lrt -lm    -L/usr/local/lib -lswscale -lavutil -lrt -lm    -lm -lpthread -ldl
```

Comment: `configure`する時にoption何付けました？こういうのって任意のoption付けてやらんとlibraryが作られんと思いますが...その辺確認されました？多分`./configure --help`とか打つとlibrary作成するoptionが確認できると思います。

Comment: `http://t-akabane.net/tips/x264/1`で確認しましたが...『--enable-shared』付けないとlibrary作られないんちゃいますかね？

Comment: そういえば、社畜根性さんが使っている OS は何でしょう？ もしかしたらパッケージをインストールすればよいだけのお話かもしれませんね。なお、Ubuntu Linux では `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx264.so.142` にあります(libx264-142 package)。

Comment: makeは成功してるのでしょうか？configure と make の実行結果が分かれば回答が得られやすいと思います。実行結果を質問内容に追記することを検討してみてください。

Comment: [Installing FFMPEG for Raspberry Pi](http://www.jeffreythompson.org/blog/2014/11/13/installing-ffmpeg-for-raspberry-pi/)

Comment: `x264$ ./configure`の結果を見る限りlibraryが出力されないようになってますね。
『shared: no』でそれが分かります。
take88さんのconfigureのoptionに『--libdir=/usr/lib』も付けてあげた方が良いのかな？

Answer (score 1):

私の環境で試しましたところ `configure`、`make`、`make install` の順でインストールできました。

> しかし、これを実行しても/usr/lib/にはなくて/usr/local/bin/にx264が追加されただけでした。

`configure` オプションに `--enable-shared` が無いので実行コマンドのみビルドされています。
インストール先を変えたいのでしたら `--prefix=/usr` を指定します。

> また、もしlibx264をインストールできたとしてもすぐにffmpegで使えますか？
>   いれたあとにffmpegをまたコンパイルする必要があるんでしょうか

Shared ライブラリなので大丈夫なのではないかと思います。
ただ、試したわけではなりませんのでご自身で確認されてみてください。

**configure オプションの確認方法**

`configure` はオプションがあるので次のようにして必要なオプションを確認します。

```
$ ./configure --help
```

必要そうなオプションは この辺りでしょうか。

```
  --prefix=PREFIX          install architecture-independent files in PREFIX [/usr/local]

  --enable-shared          build shared library
```

私の環境だと次のオプションも必要でした。

```
  --disable-asm            disable platform-specific assembly optimizations
```

**configure の実行例**

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared --disable-asm
Warning: libavformat is not supported without swscale support
platform:      X86_64
byte order:    little-endian
system:        LINUX
cli:           yes
libx264:       internal
shared:        yes
static:        no
asm:           no
interlaced:    yes
avs:           avxsynth
lavf:          no
ffms:          no
mp4:           no
gpl:           yes
thread:        posix
opencl:        yes
filters:       crop select_every
debug:         no
gprof:         no
strip:         no
PIC:           yes
bit depth:     8
chroma format: all

You can run 'make' or 'make fprofiled' now.
```

**make & make install の実行例**

```
$ make
cat common/opencl/x264-cl.h common/opencl/bidir.cl common/opencl/downscale.cl common/opencl/intra.cl common/opencl/motionsearch.cl common/opencl/subpel.cl common/opencl/weightp.cl | ./tools/cltostr.sh common/oclobj.h
dependency file generation...
(略)

$ sudo make install
install -d /usr/local/bin
install x264 /usr/local/bin
install -d /usr/local/include
install -d /usr/local/lib
install -d /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
install -m 644 ./x264.h /usr/local/include
install -m 644 x264_config.h /usr/local/include
install -m 644 x264.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
ln -f -s libx264.so.148 /usr/local/lib/libx264.so
install -m 755 libx264.so.148 /usr/local/lib
```

**インストール先の確認**

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/lib
合計 1052
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      14 10月  5 12:23 2015 libx264.so -> libx264.so.148
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1071160 10月  5 12:23 2015 libx264.so.148
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    4096 10月  5 12:34 2015 pkgconfig
```